# What is the meaning of "На скорині сіли" in the song Гречаники?

Tags: значення-слів

I discovered *[this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsdvKAK3qaA)* and I'm trying to decipher the meaning:

> Гоп, мой гречаники,
>    Гоп, мої білі,
>    Чогось мої гречаники
>    **На скорині сіли**.
>    Гоп, мої гречаники,
>    Гоп, мої смачні,
>    Чогось мої гречаники
>    Не вдалися вдачні.

I found the following definition for **[скорина](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)**:

> [image]

Does it mean that they turned into balls of hard-crusted substance? What is the meaning of **сiли** then? "To shrink"? Why is the preposition **на** used here? It does not mean "upon, on the surface" in this case, does it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Admittedly, this is one tough question. I had to ask an elder person to understand it even to myself. :-) **This phrase can be roughly translated, "lost its shape, flaked".**

*Гречаники*, buckwheat cutlets, are cooked so that they kept their thick shape — primarily because the surface gets crusty first and keeps the shape of each individual cutlet throughout the cooking time.

[image: гречаники]

If, however, the dough (or should I call it mince?) was too liquid or the proper cooking temperature was not kept, the cutlets can flake (***сісти***, "to shrink"), sometimes even merging into a single messy "pancake" underneath. This "pancake" itself becomes a crusty surface (***скорина***) underneath when cooked.

This is why the lyrics says,

> Чогось мої гречаники
>   Не вдалися вдачні

In other words, the cutlets were unsuccessful because it lost its shape and it formed a crusty "pancake" underneath.

The picture below does *not* show unsuccessful *гречаники*; it shows *гречаники* under sour cream sauce, but it demonstrates the flake underneath:

[image: гречаники під соусом]

Comment: Дякую! So the preposition "**на**" does not always mean "on top of something" in Ukrainian, unlike in Russian. Interesting.

Comment: @CopperKettle, I beiieve, here it means "on top of" (…the crusty pancake). However, the verb *"сісти"* has two meanings, "sit" and "shrink", and this folk song seems to primarily use the latter.

Comment: My attempt: **[Grechanicki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk5K5.png)** (0: